# Creating .ase (ASCII EXPORT) file in blender or from .obj / .3ds file

Tags: 3d, blender, .obj, 3ds

I have a code  that parses .ase files, but all the models I found were in .obg/.blender/.3ds formats.

I couldn't find a way to translate them to each other how is tat possible to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't deal particularly with .ase files, but I do a lot of translation from different object formats.  I've had the best success with Blender.  A quick google search yields a plugin for import/export of .ase files.  I haven't tested it, but I would imagine it's a great path to start.  After importing the .obj/.3ds/etc into blender, you can then export to the .ase format.

http://www.katsbits.com/smforum/index.php?topic=147.0

Comment: I did that but every time I tried to export my any of my files to ase format it makes an error:

No UV texture Data